# Package Conflict in Flutter how to resolve?

Tags: flutter, package, conflict

When creating a QR Code reader app in VSCode, I wanted to use two different packages and implement certain functionalities from both, since one package has some functionality that the other does not.

The two packages in question are:

1. [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)
2. [qrscan](https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan)

While I had been working on the project with only the first (qr_code_scanner) package added to my pubspec.yaml, the project could compile and run. However, once I added the second (qrscan) package to my pubspec.yaml, my project could not compile and would show the error.

```
\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\qrcodereader\MainActivity.kt: (14, 49): Unresolved reference: onFlutterViewDestroyed
```

Wondering if it is possible to resolve this issue, or if not possible, how I can restore to a previously working state, since removing either package from my pubspec.yaml does not remove the package from my flutter project.

If required, flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 84f3d28555 (5 days ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
    • Engine revision b8752bbfff
    • Dart version 2.10.2

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Daniel Seah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Daniel Seah\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.1

[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry but I could not find any solution for this

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48063#issuecomment-778080301 "onFlutterViewDestroyed" is changed